# Is the time "15:43:38" special for a Fermi-LAT mission?

Tags: astrophysics

I was reading [a paper about the ANITA balloon-borne experiment](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02869). In Table 1 in the paper, the experiment times for 'flaring blazers searches' are denoted as 'year-month-day 15:43:38Z + weeks'. In the caption of the table the authors explain that the number "15:43:38Z" is an offset and is related to the Fermi-LAT mission. However, I'm totally puzzled what this means. Can someone please explain how the number "15:43:38Z" can be related to the Fermi-LAT mission? For example, does Fermi-LAT restart its observation everyday at that time..?

Comment: The  Z presumably stands for *Zulu* time, This being another name for  UCT (or GMT).

Answer (score 1):

15:43:38Z literally means 3:53 pm plus 38 seconds Zulu time or Greenwich Mean Time GMT or Coordinated Universal Time UTC.

In the table description it also states "*The times
for the flaring blazar search are one-week time scales based on the Fermi telescope’s elapsed mission
time, hence the offset of 15:43:38 for each start time.*"

The offset time is the amount of time added/removed to/from the UTC time to give you the current time (standard time or daylight saving time).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I'm afraid I still don't understand .. 'based on the Fermi telescope’s elapsed mission time, hence the offset of 15:43:38 for each start time'. I wonder why most of the flaring blazar searches start at this time. Could there be any reason to select data that way? Normally, people want to maximize the livetime or make a careful selection of the time window. Thus, it looks strange that many of the periods start at that time. Also, would it have something to do with the Fermi-LAT mission time?